# When I push elements into array the first one is removed and is replaced by the recent one

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I want to add elements into array and when I add it,the first one is replaced by the recent one, so and so forth so how do I push dynamicly without the previous once not replaced

I want to add elements into array and when I add it,the first one is replaced by the recent one, so and so forth so how do I push dynamicly without the previous once not replaced.

```
  let calculator = document.querySelector(".calculator"),


calc_screen = document.querySelector(".calculator-screen"),

calc_keys = document.querySelector(".calculator-keys");



try{
 calculator,
 calc_screen,
 calc_keys
 }catch(error){
 console.log("this doesn't exist")
 }



 calculator.addEventListener("click",function(e){




 let arr = [];


 arr.push(e.target.textContent)

 console.log(arr)



   if(e.target === calc_keys){
     e.stopPropagation(calc_keys)
   }else{
    calc_screen.value+=e.target.textContent;








       let operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");


 operators.forEach(function(op){

   if(calc_screen.value[0] === op.textContent){

     calc_screen.value = calc_screen.value.slice(1)
   }

 })

   }

  if(calc_screen.value.includes("AC")){
    calc_screen.value = "";
  }


// if(calc_screen.value[0] === ""){
 //  alert(true)
// }
```

})

Comment: Are you setting `let arr = []` inside of a loop or an event callback? If so it will get reset every iteration. Youll need to set `let arr = []` at the root level of the block scope.

Comment: I don't know how I will be happy if you showed me.

Comment: Show more of your code so I can see where you're messing up.

Comment: I edited the question look again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is resetting `arr` on click.

```
calculator.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    let arr = [];
    arr.push(e.target.textContent);
```

set it before

```
let arr = [];
calculator.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    arr.push(e.target.textContent);
```

Comment: What I am trying to say is that I want to push elements into array without replacing the first one. do that with regular array I will figure out the rest.

Comment: This will keep all instances. Wont replace anything